# How i can disable Full Screen Button in JWplayer by code?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html

I don't want Full Screen Button to be clear in JWplayer. what part should change till Full Screen button to be disable? This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
<script data-cfasync='false' src='http://jwpsrv.com/library/SakQCEfSEeOHhRIxOQfUww.js'></script>
<div id='playerjxJRqLMFuJaA'></div>
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerjxJRqLMFuJaA').setup({
    file: 'http://TV.b-c-e.us@cdn-01.bonus-tv.ru:8080/matchtv/index.m3u8',
 aboutlink: 'http://tv.b-c-e.us',
        enableFullscreen: 'false',
        title: 'Live Stream',
        width: '890',
        height: '640',
        stretching: 'exactfit',
        autostart: 'true',
        primary: 'flash',
 skin: 'bekle',
 androidhls: 'true',


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the full screen button disappear, use this css:

```
.jw-icon-fullscreen {
    display: none;
}
```

But beware that it **will not disable** the button, **just hide** it.

Ref: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_reference/

@Edit:
Maybe you can use javascript to block it:

```
var fullScreenBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-icon-fullscreen');
for(var i in fullScreenBtns){
    var btn = fullScreenBtns[i];
    btn.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Full screen is blocked');
        return false;
    };
}
```

I could not find it in the documentation through...

Comment: is there another way? without css?

Comment: @AurefPourkarimi maybe with a bit  of js... I updated my answer